# JQuery AJAX: Update ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a strongly-typed MVC view that includes a form with an editor that is bound to a view model:

```
@model ViewModels.CommentView
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateComments", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Metadata</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="action clear">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When the user clicks on an element in a different part of the view, a JQuery AJAX call retrieves data from the server and updates the control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".load-comments").focus(function () {
        var Id = $("#Id").val();
        var url = "@Url.Action("GetComment")/" + Id;
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: DataRetrieved, type: 'POST', dataType: 'json' });
        function DataRetrieved(data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#Comment").val(data.Comment);
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

This functionality works as expected: the control content is visually updated. However, the value of the underlying html element is not updated, and when I post the form back to the server, the view model is empty.

How do I set the form controls' value in the JQuery function so that they post back to the server?

Comment: Do you see the value change in the HTML-page? If it is correctly changed, then the element is updated.

Comment: @Kenneth, no - at least not using Firebug and the markup inspector in Chrome. However, the fields *appear* to be correctly updated when I view the page in the browser.

Comment: Hmm, that is very weird. If you see the value change it should be visible in the developer tools. Could you check what is sent to the server by using a tool like HttpFiddler?

Comment: As far as I can see, it all works correctly. The request gets a 200 status, and the response is a JSON object that contains the data I expect. If I debug the JQuery function, it sets the val() property of the correct element. But the element value attribute does not reflect the update in the source.

Comment: What does it say when you execute this from the console: `$("#Comment").val()`. Have you tried checking with HttpFiddler (or the chrome network tools) what is exactly sent to the server? I think the value is actually updated correctly and sent to the server correctly but that there's something wrong with the automatic model binding.

Comment: Renders `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment)` a simple `input` element? What is sent over the wire when submitting the modified form for the field comment?

Comment: @Jan, yes, a simple input element. If I submit the form, the values are as if the AJAX update had never happened.

Comment: @PaulTaylor How did you set the HTML? ASP.NET default ModelBinder looks for id that are equals object properties to build the model back in the server. Looks like your form HTML doesnot reflect the object. Inspect each element created by Html helper and create each control as the same after coment data comes from the request. Hopes its help you!

Comment: Have you checked with fiddler whats exactly sent to the server? Cause you wrote *the viewmodel is empty*? Can you post the signature of your action and the model class?

Comment: @Kenneth, `$("#Comment").val()` shows the correct value

Comment: @Fals, I think you are on to something there. I have simplified the code above to make it simpler to read, but actually the element names are complex, derived from a property of a parent viewmodel. I'll try to match the element names to the UpdateComment argument names and see if that fixes it.

Comment: OK, then the value is correctly set. Now there are two possible problems: 1. The value is not sent to the server (highly unlikely), 2. When the value arrives on the server it's not correctly parsed in the model binder. First, eliminate the first option by checking with fiddler or the chrome/firebug-tools. Next, please post your complete Model and the Action-method of your controller

Comment: Ok, fixed it, the problem was with the model binding as both Kenneth and Fals suggested. The firebug/chrome symptoms were a red herring. If someone posts that, I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: @PaulTaylor You can create a custom ModelBinder to Bind your model back in the server, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you set the HTML? ASP.NET default ModelBinder looks for id that are equals object properties to build the model back in the server. Looks like your form HTML doesnot reflect the object. Inspect each element created by Html helper and create each control as the same after comment data comes from the request. Hopes its help you! You can create a custom ModelBinder to Bind your model back in the server, take a look here: [Model Biding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)